# How to solve 403 error on WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with a valid JWT?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've looked at pretty much all of the blogs and SO posts on this topic and I'm not seeing a solution. I have a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that looks like this:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  String issuerUri = "issuer url";

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
            authorizeRequests
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/test").hasRole("Task.Write")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
            oauth2ResourceServer
                .jwt(jwt ->
                    jwt.decoder(JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuerUri))
                )
        );
  }
```

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
@GetMapping(value="/test")
public ApplicationResponse test(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt) {
    // Map<String, Object> x = jwt.getClaims();
    return new ApplicationResponse("ok", "ok");
}
```

However when I hit this endpoint with Postman with a valid JWT I get a 403 error. I have tried prefixing the role with `ROLE_` and `Role_` and tried numerous other things but it always is 403.

What's weird too is if I do a `permitAll()` instead of the authenticate and let the JWT go through. I can look into the JWT object in the controller. I see that the role is there. So why does this `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` always throw a 403 when the JWT is valid and the role is there?

I noticed that the roles are located in the claim in the JWT. Maybe I need to get it from here? I don't see how to get roles from claims in the configure method:

[image]

Comment: To clarify the issuerUrl in my code is correct in my code i changed it to the above to conceal the URL. Thanks.

Comment: It is Task.Write. I read it is good to prefix it with Role_ so I tried that amongst other things

Comment: The role has to be `ROLE_Task.Write`. Maybe the dot is the problem.Could you change it to `ROLE_Task_Write` and in your configuration to `hasRole("Task_Write")`?

Comment: This seems really crazy. Are you sure I have to change the role values to ROLE_? It seems like you should be able to pass whatever values. I have other applications that need these roles so I would have to go make a code change to those apps if I do this.

Comment: Did not work for some reason. I am going to try just Task_Write without the period and without the ROLE_ ... but it's not propagated through the system yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please enable debug logs and update your question with the logs.

Comment: roles in jwt is not standard, that is a custom claim that needs to be extracted and added to the UserDetailsObject. But one should not place roles in a jwt, common practice is  usually use JWTs for authentication, not authorization.

Comment: Ok thanks I got it working by getting the role from the claim and also adding an annotation. But what do you mean you wouldn’t add the role to the jwt? This jwt came from Microsoft so I’m assuming they’re doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Security converts the items in the `scope` or `scp` claim and uses the `SCOPE_` prefix. You can change both conventions by defining a custom `JwtAuthenticationConverter` bean.

To export authorities from a `roles` scope and use the `ROLE_` prefix, you can define the following converter, so that you can use methods like `hasRole("Task_Write")`.

```
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```